# Symfony2 - Change Page Content - Like Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, twig

I am evaluating an ArrayCollection in my Template like this:

```
{% for article in articles %}
   <li
      {% if article.new %}
         class="new"
      {% endif %}
   >{{ article.name|e }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Now I want to reload the articles ArrayCollection without reloading the whole page, like you would do in Ajax. Is it possible to reload it and let twig evaluate all the articles in a loop like the above?

**I want to use twig to evaluate the content**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, yes. You just need to make an ajax request to the action that'd return rendered collection.
This can be achieved by creating new action (recommended) or adding new paramenters in request that would tell twig which part to render or not (easier to do, harder to maintain).

#### Edit

Extending my answer because author requested me to.

Lets assume `News` controller in `YourNs\YourBundle`
Its contents should looks somewhat like this:

```
class NewsController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/articles")
     * @Template()
     */
     public function listAction(){
         $articles = $this->yourMethodToFindArticles();
         return compact('articles');
     }
}
```

Next thing to do is to render this action by adding `YourNs/YourBundle/Resources/views/News/list.html.twig` file and filling it up.

Once you have it done you'll need to add functionality to fire up ajax request to fetch refreshed collection of articles. [FOSJsRouting](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/) might prove useful for that as well.

You can either add new action to controller

```
    /**
     * @Route("/_api/articles-list")
     * @Template()
     */
     public function apiListAction(){
         $articles = $this->yourMethodToFindArticles();
         return compact('articles');
     }
```

And make its template render just your collection.

Or parametrize your first action and render template according to that:

```
{% if app.request.query.get('partial') %}
Template elements
{% endif %}
{% for article in articles %}
<li
  {% if article.new %}
     class="new"
  {% endif %}
>{{ article.name|e }}</li>
{% endfor %}
{% if app.request.query.get('partial') %}
Other template elements
{% endif %}
```

Second solution is clearly inferior to the first one, especially once you start using esi tags, if you do that your code would look like this:

```
class NewsController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/articles")
     * @Template()
     */
     public function listAction(){
         return [];
     }

    /**
     * @Route("/_api/articles-list")
     * @Template()
     */
     public function apiListAction(){
         $articles = $this->yourMethodToFindArticles();
         return compact('articles');
     }
}
```

And listAction() template:

```
Template elements
{{ render_esi(url('yourns_yourbundle_news_apilist' }}
Other template elements
```

Note that the above snippets are just a simplified solution explaining trivial issue.

#### Edit2

Example of fetching that uses FOSJsRouting, js code with the api action:

```
var url = Routing.generate('yourns_yourbundle_news_apilist')
var fetchedCollection = $.get(url);
```

And example with parametrized template:

```
var url = Routing.generate('yourns_yourbundle_news_list', {'partial': 'true'})
var fetchedCollection = $.get(url);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you at least add some code snippets/links/whatever, so I can understand, how to achieve the rerendering and so on? Especially how to tell twig to rerender the collection and how to pass the collection to a ajax request.

Comment: @Robin I have added some more explanation on the ideas.

Comment: Thank you. This seems pretty nice. Just one Question: As far as I understand your answer, you will load the articles one time on page load. But how do you reload just the articles, for example if I press a Button or after some time or what ever? This is my main problem. +1

Comment: Lets assume you went for the better solution with adding api action, if you have the FOSJsRouting you'll just need to execute simple code like this: 
`$.get(Routing.generate('yourns_yourbundle_news_apilist'));`

Comment: Ok, so now I call the method and will get the new Articles. Will twig automatically reload the list?

Comment: @Robin: Well once you fetched the collection you just need to replace old html with new one, but that are __basics__ of dom manipulation with js

Comment: Ah, you are right. I didn't understand that `fetchedCollection` will contain the `HTML` generated by `Twig`. This seems like a really good solution. Thank you very much for your effort.